# Android Studio network monitor on 3.5 issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

What happened to the Network Monitor on android studio 3.5 on Stable channel ?

I select a portion and i don't get any calls. I get all sorts of calls with 0 data sent and received. Is there a bug in the new Android Studio or am I doing something wrong? The calls listed in the pic below were not made in during that selected timeframe. I guess there's an issue with refreshing the Connection View section or ... ?!

Ideas ?!

[image]

Comment: It's ironic that they call 3.5 stable even though it feels more like an Alpha. Anyway, have you tried out 3.5.1? Not sure if this issue is fixed there

Comment: I am not willing to move from the Stable channel, I can't risk it. So then ... there's a bug in the IDE, from what I can gather. It's not only me then .. ?

Comment: No it's not just you. I'm experiencing multiple bugs as well, most noticeably the XML auto formatting. Anyway, there's 0 risk with using a test version of Android Studio, especially if you use a source control system like Git. Oh and you can run multiple versions of Android Studio at the same time

Comment: Does the XML auto formatting this issue move your views around in the layout by any chance? It reorderes Views around ... ?

Comment: yes that issue...

Comment: I had that issue as well, found a solution here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620225/android-reformat-code-option-rearranges-the-order-of-my-views-in-the-layout